# Quickly Create A Java Class Object

Tags: java, class, object, runtime

So, I'm working on a small (but still tedious) amount of Class, in exact number, 20 class, but that doesn't matter.

One of the thing my program will do is to read an input of 2 parameter, (String className, String name), and add a new object with the class name of className with a parameter of name for it's constructor.

So, imagine Dog, Cat, Pig, Moth, Mouse, bla...
each of them take the same constructor, just different classes.
Instead of doing

```
if (className.equalsIgnoreCase("Dog")){
     myArrayList.add(new Dog(name));
} else if (className.equalsIgnoreCase("Cat")){
     myArrayList.add(new Cat(name));
} else if (...)
```

is there a way to make it so that I can just simply do

```
myArrayList.add(new X(name));
```

or something familiar to it?

Answer (score 0):

If all the classes are in the same package you can use reflection:

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("your.package." + className);
Constructor<?> constructor = clazz.getConstructor(String.class);
myArrayList.add((CommonParent) constructor.newInstance(name));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like this. This example is without Spring Framework, but with Spring framework it can be a bit simpler.

1. Define interface for factories

```java
    public interface AnimalFactory<T extends Animal> {
        boolean isFactoryForType(String type);
        Animal createWithName(String name);
    }
```

2. Implement factories

```java
    public class DogFactory implements AnimalFactory<Dog> {

        @Override
        public boolean isFactoryForType(String type) {
            return "dog".equalsIgnoreCase(type);
        }

        @Override
        public Dog createWithName(String name) {
            return new Dog(name);
        }
    }
```

```java
    public class CatFactory implements AnimalFactory<Cat> {

        @Override
        public boolean isFactoryForType(String type) {
            return "cat".equalsIgnoreCase(type);
        }

        @Override
        public Cat createWithName(String name) {
            return new Cat(name);
        }

    }
```

3. Example of a Dog

```java
    public class Dog extends Animal {
        public Dog(String name) {
            super(name);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "This is a Dog with name: " + getName();
        }
    }
```

4. Example usage

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.err.println("Expect type AND name as input arguments");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String type = args[0];
        String name = args[1];

        List<AnimalFactory<? extends Animal>> animalFactories = new ArrayList<>();
        animalFactories.add(new DogFactory());
        animalFactories.add(new CatFactory());

        AnimalFactory<?> animalFactory = animalFactories.stream()
                .filter(factory -> factory.isFactoryForType(type))
                .findFirst()
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Type " + type + " not supported"));

        Animal animal = animalFactory.createWithName(name);

        System.out.println("Created animal: " + animal);
    }
```

5. Output with arguments: dog Boris

`Created animal: This is a Dog with name: Boris`

5. Output with arguments: car Bill

`Created animal: This is a Cat with name: Bill`